# Issues with DDPG Algorithm in MuJoCo Environment - Consistent Incorrect Path Generation

Tags: python

Problem Description:
I'm utilizing Stable Baselines3's DDPG algorithm for a task in a MuJoCo environment, aiming to navigate a robotic arm to a fixed target. However, I'm encountering persistent issues:

Environment with Fixed Target Position: Initially, the target's position was static. Despite this, the trained model consistently moves along an incorrect path, failing to reach the target.

Adding Randomness and Obstacles: To improve performance, I modified the environment to randomize the target's position on each reset and introduced obstacles for an obstacle-avoidance task. Yet, even in this varied environment, the model still outputs a fixed, incorrect path.

Attempted Solutions:

I've tried adjusting training parameters and altering the reward function, but the issue persists.
Questions:

Where might the problem lie in this scenario? Is it an issue with the algorithm implementation or the environment setup?
Are there any recommended debugging techniques or suggestions for improvement?
Thank you for your assistance and advice!

The following is the code for the environment part I created through mujoco. The displayed code omits a portion of the code.

```
import numpy as np
import mujoco
from gymnasium import Env
import mujoco.viewer
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from gymnasium.spaces import Box


class RobotEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self, robot_xml, ball_xml, box_xml):
        self.merged_xml, self.body_names = self.merge_xmls(robot_xml, ball_xml, box_xml)
        self.model = mujoco.MjModel.from_xml_path(self.merged_xml)
        self.data = mujoco.MjData(self.model)
        self.viewer = None

        self.step_count = 0 
        self.total_collision_count = 0 
        max_linear_change = 0.05
        max_angle_change_radians = np.radians(10)
        low_action = np.array([-max_linear_change]*5 + [-max_angle_change_radians]*3)
        high_action = np.array([max_linear_change]*5 + [max_angle_change_radians]*3)
        self.action_space = Box(low_action, high_action, dtype=np.float32)
        
        max_distance = 2.0  
        max_collisions = 30 
        max_steps = 50 
        low_obs = np.array([0, 0, 0])
        high_obs = np.array([max_distance, max_collisions, max_steps])
        obstacle_low = np.array([-10, -10, -10] * 7)
        obstacle_high = np.array([10, 10, 10] * 7)
        zedmini_low = np.array([-3, -3, -3])
        zedmini_high = np.array([3, 3, 3])
        low_obs = np.concatenate([low_obs, obstacle_low, zedmini_low])
        high_obs = np.concatenate([high_obs, obstacle_high, zedmini_high])

        self.observation_space = Box(low_obs, high_obs, dtype=np.float32)

#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    def merge_xmls(self, main_xml, *additional_xmls):
        main_tree = ET.parse(main_xml)
        main_root = main_tree.getroot()

        body_names = []
        main_tendon = main_root.find("tendon")
        if main_tendon is None:
            main_tendon = ET.SubElement(main_root, "tendon")

        for add_xml in additional_xmls:
            add_tree = ET.parse(add_xml)
            add_root = add_tree.getroot()
            for elem in add_root.find("worldbody"):
                main_root.find("worldbody").append(elem)
                body_names.append(elem.get('name'))  
            add_tendon = add_root.find("tendon")
            if add_tendon is not None:
                for spatial in add_tendon:
                    main_tendon.append(spatial)

        merged_path = "merged.xml"
        with open(merged_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(ET.tostring(main_root))
        return merged_path, body_names

    def reset(self, seed=None, return_info=False, options=None):
        if seed is not None:
            np.random.seed(seed)

        self.place_random_obstacle_and_target()
        if self.viewer is not None:
            self.viewer.sync()
        self.total_collision_count = 0 
        self.step_count = 0  

        observation = self.get_observation() 
        print("observation",observation)
        info = {} 
        return observation, info  

    def seed(self, seed=None):
        self.np_random, seed = gym.utils.seeding.np_random(seed)
        return [seed]

    def place_random_obstacle_and_target(self):
        bbox_min = np.array([-0.5, -0.5, 0])
        bbox_max = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.8])
        target_pos = [0.3, 0.2, 0.3]
        self.set_body_position("target", target_pos, bbox_min, bbox_max)  
        active_obstacles = np.random.randint(1, 3)
        for i in range(1, active_obstacles + 1):
            obstacle_pos = [0, 0, 0]
            self.set_body_position(f"obstacle{i}", obstacle_pos, bbox_min, bbox_max)
            self.set_site_position(f"fixed_point{i}", obstacle_pos) 

        for i in range(active_obstacles + 1, len(self.body_names)):
            self.set_body_position(f"obstacle{i}", [10, 10, 10], bbox_min, bbox_max)
            self.set_site_position(f"fixed_point{i}", [10, 10, 10])  

        if self.viewer is not None:
            self.viewer.sync()

    def set_site_position(self, site_name, position):
        site_id = mujoco.mj_name2id(self.model, mujoco.mjtObj.mjOBJ_SITE, site_name)
        if site_id == -1:
            return

        self.model.site_pos[site_id] = position
        mujoco.mj_forward(self.model, self.data)


    def set_body_position(self, body_name, position, bbox_min, bbox_max, max_trials=10):
        joint_name = body_name 
        joint_id = mujoco.mj_name2id(self.model, mujoco.mjtObj.mjOBJ_JOINT, joint_name) 
        if joint_id == -1:
            return
        qpos_start = self.model.jnt_qposadr[joint_id] 

        trial_count = 0
        while trial_count < max_trials:
            self.data.qpos[qpos_start:qpos_start+3] = position
            mujoco.mj_forward(self.model, self.data)
            
            if self.data.ncon == 0: 
                break
            
            position = np.random.uniform(bbox_min, bbox_max)
            trial_count += 1
        
        if trial_count == max_trials:
            print(f"警告: 尝试了 {max_trials} 次还是有碰撞发生.")



    def step(self, action):
        joint_names = [
            "Y_linear_joint",
            "X_linear_joint",
            "Z1_linear_joint",
            "Z2_linear_joint",
            "Z3_linear_joint",
            "yaw_joint",
            "pitch_joint",
            "roll_joint"
        ]
        current_joint_positions = np.array([self.data.qpos[mujoco.mj_name2id(self.model, mujoco.mjtObj.mjOBJ_JOINT, jn)] for jn in joint_names])
   
        target_positions = current_joint_positions + action
    
        for idx, joint_name in enumerate(joint_names):
            joint_id = mujoco.mj_name2id(self.model, mujoco.mjtObj.mjOBJ_JOINT, joint_name)
            self.data.ctrl[joint_id] = target_positions[idx]
        

        mujoco.mj_step(self.model, self.data)
        

        self.step_count += 1
        observation = self.get_observation()
        reward = self.get_reward(observation)
        done = self.check_done(observation)
        

        truncated = self.step_count >= 50 #max_steps
        if done and not truncated:
            truncated = False
        elif not done and truncated:
            done = False
        #print(f"action: {action}")
        #print(f"target_positions: {target_positions}")
        return observation, reward, done, truncated, {}


    def get_observation(self):
        #zedmini_position = self.data.body_xpos[self.model.body_name2id("zedmini")]
        body_id = mujoco.mj_name2id(self.model, mujoco.mjtObj.mjOBJ_BODY, "zedmini")
        zedmini_position = self.data.xpos[body_id]  # Assuming xpos is a flat array
        target_id = mujoco.mj_name2id(self.model, mujoco.mjtObj.mjOBJ_BODY, "target")
        target_position = self.data.xpos[target_id]  
        print("target_position",target_id,target_position)
        #print("zedmini_position",zedmini_position,"target_position",target_position)
        distance = np.linalg.norm(zedmini_position - target_position)
        #print("distance",distance)

        collision_count = self.count_collisions()
        total_collision_count = self.total_collision_count

        obstacle_positions = []
        target_id = mujoco.mj_name2id(self.model, mujoco.mjtObj.mjOBJ_BODY, f"target")
        target_position = self.data.xpos[target_id]
        obstacle_positions.append(target_position)
        for i in range(1, 7):  
            obstacle_id = mujoco.mj_name2id(self.model, mujoco.mjtObj.mjOBJ_BODY, f"obstacle{i}")
            obstacle_position = self.data.xpos[obstacle_id]
            obstacle_positions.append(obstacle_position)


        obstacle_positions_flat = np.concatenate(obstacle_positions)
        zedmini_position_flat = zedmini_position
        observation = np.concatenate(
            [np.array([distance, total_collision_count, self.step_count]), obstacle_positions_flat, zedmini_position_flat]
        ).astype(np.float32)
        return observation


    def get_reward(self, observation):
        distance_reward = 100 - observation[0] / 5.0 
        collision_penalty = 5 * observation[1]  
        movement_penalty = 1 * observation[2]  
        reward = distance_reward - collision_penalty - movement_penalty
        if self.check_done(observation): 
            reward += 300
        return reward

    def check_done(self, observation):
        done = observation[0] <= 0.1  
        return bool(done)  
####################
    def render(self, mode='none'):
        if mode == 'human':
            if self.viewer is None:
                self.viewer = mujoco.viewer.launch_passive(self.model, self.data)
            while self.viewer.is_running():
                mujoco.mj_step(self.model, self.data) 
                self.viewer.sync() 
        elif mode == 'none':
            # Do not render anything
            pass
```